# Tangent vectors as curves equivalence relation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, manifolds

I do not understand the definition of the equivalence relation that is defined on the curves creating a tangent vector space.

Let $X$ be any manifold, a point $x \in X$, two curves $\alpha:(-a,a) \to X, \beta:(-b,b) \to X$. Then $\alpha$ is equivalent to $\beta$ at $x$ iff $\alpha(0)=x, \beta(0)=x$ and for a chart $\phi:X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to some euclidean space $(\phi \circ \alpha)'(0)=(\phi \circ \beta)'(0)$.

The first point I do not understand is why we need a chart at all, it is a bijection so it should be true$(\phi \circ \alpha)'(0)=(\phi \circ \beta)'(0)$ iff $(\alpha)'(0)=(\beta)'(0)$.

Secondly imagine curves $\alpha(t)=(t,t), \beta(t)=(2t,2t)$ to euclidean space with their identity chart. Such curves have at every point the same direction, however their derivative is different, therefore such curves would not be equivalent at $t=0$ according to that definition.

Therefore the tangent space $T_xX$ consists of equivalence classes of curves at $x$ that do not have the same direction only, but their derivatives (vectors) have the same magnitude too. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second question, yes, the tangent space $T_xX$ consists of *vectors*, so not only direction but magnitude matters as well. Actually, $T_xX$ is *isomorphic* to the vector space $\Bbb R^n$, using a fixed chart.

The point is that, we a priori *don't know yet* what tangent vectors are in an abstract manifold $X$, though $\alpha'(0)$ should be a tangent vector, an element of $T_{\alpha(0)}X$, which we are *about to define* just now. That's why chart is needed, as differentiation and vectors are already defined in $\Bbb R^n$, and we can use those.